# Remove line breaks between certain lines in python

Tags: python

I have a txt file which has data in this form:

```
Fact 1:
YouTube has over
1 Billion users daily`


Fact 2:
Owls don't sleep
at night
```

What I want is to get one fact per line like this:

```
Fact 1: YouTube has over 1 Billion users daily
Fact 2: Owls don't sleep at night
```

I tried using `strip()` like

```html
with open("facts.txt", 'r', encoding = "utf-8") as f:
    lines = f.read()
    lines.strip("\n")
```

But it isn't working.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the file's content is always in that form:

- Split lines with 1 `'\n'`
- Join back the list with 1 space `(' ')`
- Replace converted 3 spaces `('   ')` to 1 `'\n'`

```
with open('facts.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    print(' '.join(lines.split('\n')).replace('   ', '\n'))
```

Or:

```
with open('facts.txt') as f: print(chr(32).join(f.read().split('\n')).replace(chr(32)*3,'\n'))
```